# Bugged Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

We got a website (happened before too) that when viewed on IE8 on 2 PC don't show as supposed, but when tested on 2 other PC using same Windows, same IE version show correctly...

I did a quick draw (pardon Ms-Paint for the bad compression/gradient), the first part (pink with red border) is the background as I see it on every browser on 4 different PC, the second part is what I see on those 2 PC. The white box (with black border) is a div which is over the pink one, but this DIV has no background, it should not "cut/hide" the other background.

So there is my question, what could cause this in general? And why those 2 PC have problem specific to them, is that possible that IE Rendering Tool have been corrupted/bugged in some sort.

[image: Problem]

Comment: No code?  Can't help you.  See the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and try again.  Even better... post some links to the page on your server.

Comment: Make sure your page has the correct `DOCTYPE` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press F-12 to open the debugger and determine which rendering mode the page is using. Make sure you're not in "quirks mode".

Comment: More likely caused by IE7-compatibility mode than quirks mode, but +1 because it's the same place to look, so close enough.